# Custom validator not working in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, validation

Why didn't it work?

If the user selects “Programmer” in the drop down list and inputs “12” to the textbox, I want the validation to fire. But nothing’s happening when I click the submit button.

```
   <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication2.WebForm1" %>

   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head runat="server">
   <script language="JavaScript">
   var text = document.getElementById("Textbox2");
   function Date(oSrc, args) {
   args.IsValid = (args.Value == "Programmer" && text == "12");
   }
   </script>

   <title></title>
   </head>
   <body>
   <form id="form1" runat="server">
   <div>

   <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
   <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
   <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
   <asp:CustomValidator ID="dateValidator" runat="server" 
   ClientValidationFunction="Date" ControlToValidate="DropDownList1" Display="Dynamic" 
   ErrorMessage="Sample error!"></asp:CustomValidator>

   <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
  <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Select a profession</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem>Programmer</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem>Lawyer</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem>Doctor</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem>Artist</asp:ListItem>
   </asp:DropDownList>

   </div>
   </form>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: If you `alert()` the values that you want to check (args.Value and text), what do you get? And what if you use Danith's version (your's has some problems that he fixed)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try below

```
<script language="JavaScript">
   function Date(oSrc, args) {
   args.IsValid = (args.Value == "Programmer" && document.getElementById('<%=TextBox2.ClientID%>').value== "12");
}
```

Comment: I already tried. Still not working. It worked on the server side. Why not in client side?

Comment: Hi I already fix the problem by replacing " with ' to the clinet side of your code. Thanks.

Comment: @user1815810 is that your answer different with mine?

Comment: No. I used your code I just typed 'Programmer' instead of "programmer" and it worked perfectly.